# Raw sockets in monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, xamarin.ios, ping

I'm trying to implement ping function in MonoTouch.
for some reasons, `Ping` class from `System.Net.NetworkInformation` doesn't work on the real device, so I decided to switch to raw sockets and implement ping myself.
Unfortunately, I'm getting "Access Denied" message on:

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp);
```

Any idea how could ping be done in monotouch? And why can't I create raw sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried raw socket but your *Access Denied* likely means they are restricted in iOS - just like they [require](http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/108252-why-root-permissions-required-creating-raw-socket.html) **root** privilege on UNIX system. This is the same reason why, in some cases, it was not possible to *directly* (workaround exists) [allow](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme.Rules.Portability#FeatureRequiresRootPrivilegeOnUnixRule) the `Ping` class to work on Mono for Linux systems.

The lack of `Ping` is a [known](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=964) issue and can *generally* be worked around by using the [Reachability](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs) helper. [Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/ReachabilitySample) code is available on GIT.

Comment: yeah, I do understand you can check reach-ability of a host with reachability class, but it is missing features like getting response time etc. will keep looking around in hope to find solution for this task

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Xamarin.iOS/MonoTouch bindings of SimplePing (which Apple says works on iOS).

https://github.com/theonlylawislove/MonoTouch.SimplePing

Check the test project for demo usage. Works on simulator and device.