# InvalidOperationException, when I use C# Ping Class to check the internet connectivity

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ping

I want to use C# Ping Class in my iOS app to check the network connectivity. But I keep getting this error: InvalidOperationException, I'm using Xamarin.ios, Can anybody help me, thank you!
this is my code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        var resultScreen = myScreen; // the results monitor
        IPAddress myIp; // the IP address

        IPAddress.TryParse(myField.Text, out myIp); // copying address from the UITextField to myIp

        pingButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
            options.DontFragment = true;
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            int timeout = 120;
            var reply = pingSender.Send(myIp.toString(), timeout, buffer,options); //the problem is here

            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {

                resultScreen.Text = reply.Address.ToString();
            }



        };
    }
```

the exception details is :

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>     at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send (System.Net.IPAddress address, Int32 timeout, System.Byte[] buffer, System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions options) [0x00051] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2922/7b89851d/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/Ping.cs:227
>     at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send (System.String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, System.Byte[] buffer, System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions options) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2922/7b89851d/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/Ping.cs:203
>     at mytest.viewController2+c__AnonStorey0.<>m__1 (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00056] in /Users/Aminzz/Projects/mytest/mytest/viewController2.cs:44
>     at UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2922/7b89851d/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs:38
>     at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2922/7b89851d/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2922/7b89851d/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:62
>     at mytest.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/Aminzz/Projects/mytest/mytest/Main.cs:12

Comment: You should parse the ip in the button click handler.  That said, I did not get an invalidoperationexception after making that change.  Could you post the exception details?

Comment: @AndrewTavera i've added the Exception details, thanks

Comment: When I tried, it was on a simulator and it worked.  I just tried on a device and got an InvalidOperationException as well.  I looked it up and it seems to be an iOS limitation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351724/ping-in-monotouch